# How to get information about websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm going to ask how to get all information as much as possible about a websites: which web server working on (IIS, Nginx,Apachi,Tomcat),which frameworks were used (jquery,MVC, angular), which tools were used (knockout,teleric) e.g. 
I've used a tool which is named Wappalyzer ( here [npm wappalyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wappalyzer/wappalyzer)) and used as a browser extension in order to do that.

[image]

It's also a good tools to get information about websites. But for some websites it can't work, and returns empty array. I was going to ask that how can I get all info from all websites without exceptions or is there any other tool to do this?

Comment: You can't get information from websites that don't provide it. There are any number of ways to shield this info.

Comment: Some websites provide that data in the response headers, some don't. It isn't up to you

Comment: How can I get this info then? Is there any other good way?

Comment: The same way as all these tools do, some of which are open-source.

Comment: can you send a site you fail to get information?

Comment: for example these websites, http://mytube.uz/      http://olx.uz/ For these sites, wappalyzer returs empty array, but in chrome extension  hows number of apps